# Fluentwait with Selenium 3.10

Tags: java, selenium

I was using selenium 2.53.1 till date and Fluentwait was working fine with it.
Now I have upgraded to Selenium 3.10 and getting an issue with using Fluentwait.

withTimeOut() and pollingEvery() methods are deprecated for the same.
Kindly give solution for the same.